# DB2 Optimistic Concurrency - RID, Row Version, Timestamp Clarifications

Tags: sql, concurrency, db2

I'm currently reading over implementing optimistic concurrency checks in DB2.  I've been mainly reading http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0801schuetz/ and http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc%2Fdoc%2Fc0051496.html (as well as some other IBM docs).

Is RID necessary when you have an ID column already?  In the 2 links they always mention use RID and row change version, however RID is row ID, so I'm not clear why I need to use it when row change token seems like SQLServer's rowversion (except for the page and not the row).

It seems as long as I have a row-change-timestamp column, then my row change token granularity will be good enough to prevent most false positives.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I read the first article is that you can use *any* of those features, you don't need to use all of them.  In particular, it appears that the row-change-timestamp is derived from `RID()` and `ROW CHANGE TOKEN`:

> **Time-based update detection:**
>   This feature is added to SQL using the
>   RID_BIT() and ROW CHANGE TOKEN. To support this feature, the table
>   needs to have a new generated column defined to store the timestamp
>   values. This can be added to existing tables using the ALTER TABLE
>   statement, or the column can be defined when creating a new table. The
>   column's existence, also affects the behavior of optimistic locking in
>   that the column if it is used to improve the granularity of the ROW
>   CHANGE TOKEN from page level to row level, which could greatly benefit
>   optimistic locking applications.

... among other things, the timestamp actually increases the granularity compared to the `ROW CHANGE TOKEN`, so it makes it easier to deal with updates.

For a number of reasons, please make sure to set the db time to UTC, as DB2 doesn't track timezone (so if you're somewhere that uses DST, the same timestamp can happen twice).

(As a side note, `RID()` isn't stable on all platforms.  On the iSeries version, at least, it changes if somebody re-orgs the table, and you may not always get the results you expect when using it with joins.  I'm also not sure about use with mirroring...)

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that if you update multiple rows in the same SQL statement execution, they will get the same timestamp (if the timestamp is updated in that statement)?

This means that a timestamp column is probably a bad choice for a unique row identifier.